# Hibernate, Jetty, H2 and Maven java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'javax.persistence.Index[] javax.persistence.Table.indexes()'

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jetty, h2

Im having trouble while trying to connect to server on localhost:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'javax.persistence.Index[] javax.persistence.Table.indexes()'

Does anyone know what may be the cause of this output?

I was trying to change the persistence version and yet it didnt help any bit.

Below my config files:

Pom.xml

```
<!--suppress ALL -->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>io.github.Dev</groupId>
    <artifactId>Hello</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>Hello World</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.25</slf4j.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!--Test-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--Logger-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Servlety-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Jetty-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.22.v20191022</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.22.v20191022</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--DB-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.200</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <plugins>
            <!--Compiler-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.0.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>jdbc:h2:file:./db</url>
                    <user>sa</user>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>

///////////////////////////Hibernate confi<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
  ~ Hibernate, Relational Persistence for Idiomatic Java
  ~
  ~ License: GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL), version 2.1 or later.
  ~ See the lgpl.txt file in the root directory or <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-2.1.html>.
  -->
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:h2:file:C:\Users\putek\IdeaProjects\_1\db</property>
        <property name="connection.username">sa</property>
        <property name="connection.password"/>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>

        <!-- Names the annotated entity class -->
        <mapping class="io.github.Dev.Lang"/>

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
//////////////////////////////////////and my HibernateUtil

public class HibernateUtil {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        StandardServiceRegistry standardRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().
                configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").build();

        Metadata metadata = new MetadataSources(standardRegistry).getMetadataBuilder().
                build();

        SessionFactoryBuilder sessionFactoryBuilder = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder();

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = sessionFactoryBuilder.build();

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }
    static void close() {
        if ( sessionFactory != null )
        {
            sessionFactory.close();
        }
    }
}
```